# Is the Special Machine Gun useful?

Tags: bionic-commando

In the original NES version of Bionic Commando, after rescuing Super Joe, he tells you where to get a "Special Machine Gun" from Destroyer 3.  I find the gun to be completely useless, so I don't get it anymore unless I'm trying to do a run with getting all items.  As far as I can tell there is no situation in which it is better than the rocket launcher; am I missing something?

Comment: Is this for the old game, or the new one?

Comment: The old one.  I had a NES tag on this at one point; I don't know what happened to it.

Comment: Generally we don't tag the platform for a game [unless the question is actually in some way about the platform or the game's interaction with it](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4639/3062), which is why it was probably removed (and why I removed it again). A tag wiki on Bionic Commando would clear this up, and I've just submitted one. That said, specifying it in the question body itself would be good too, so I made that edit as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple wiki search tells us that:

> Joe's machine gun is considerably more powerful in the meet with enemy sequences because it fires very quickly and covers a decent area with it's fire.

This is probably the only instance where Joe's Machine Gun is actually useful.

Source: [http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Reviews/BionicCommando/Wiki/index.php?title=Joe's_machine_gun](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Reviews/BionicCommando/Wiki/index.php?title=Joe%27s_machine_gun)